# adding character values in java

Tags: java, character

```
import java.awt.*; //Container, GridLayout, *, or etc...
import javax.swing.*; //JFrame, JLabel, *, or etc...
import java.awt.event.*;
public class NumerologyEC extends JFrame
{
    private static final int Width = 400;
    private static final int Height = 200;

    private JLabel wordJL, sumJL;
    private JTextField wordTF, sumTF;

    private JButton calculateJB, exitJB;

    private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

   public  NumerologyEC()
   {
       setTitle ("Numerology Extra Credit");
       wordJL = new JLabel ("Enter a word: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

       sumJL = new JLabel ("Sum of letters: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

       wordTF = new JTextField(10);

       sumTF = new JTextField(10);

       calculateJB = new JButton ("Calculate");
       cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
       calculateJB.addActionListener (cbHandler);

       exitJB = new JButton ("Exit");
       ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
       exitJB.addActionListener (ebHandler);

       Container pane = getContentPane();
       pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (3, 2));

       pane.add(wordJL);
       pane.add(wordTF);
       pane.add(calculateJB);
       pane.add(exitJB);
       pane.add(sumJL);
       pane.add(sumTF);


       setSize(Width, Height);
       setVisible (true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class CalculateButtonHandler  implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            double letterSum;

            letterSum = sumCharValues;


        }
    }

    private int sumCharValues (String input){
        String total = input.toLowerCase();
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0, n = total.length(); i < n; i++) {
            char c = total.charAt(i);
            result += (c - 'a' + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
          System.exit (0);  
        }
    }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    NumerologyEC rectObject = new NumerologyEC();
    }


}
```

How do i implement the sumcharvalues function in the "private class CalculateButtonHandler  implements ActionListener?" im trying to add up the value of the characters. just a beginner here guys. thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is it working? Try to explain the problem better. Also don't forget that a call to a function is like `sumCharValues()` not `sumCharValues`.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum characters by casting to int before performing the arithmetic.
e.g.

```
result += ((int) c) - ((int) 'a') + 1
```

That may be overparenthesized, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
package fileoperations;

import java.awt.*; //Container, GridLayout, *, or etc...

import javax.swing.*; //JFrame, JLabel, *, or etc...

import java.awt.event.*;

public class NumerologyEC extends JFrame
{
    private static final int Width = 400;
    private static final int Height = 200;

    private JLabel wordJL, sumJL;
    private JTextField wordTF, sumTF;

    private JButton calculateJB, exitJB;

    private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

   public  NumerologyEC()
   {
       setTitle ("Numerology Extra Credit");
       wordJL = new JLabel ("Enter a word: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

       sumJL = new JLabel ("Sum of letters: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

       wordTF = new JTextField(10);

       sumTF = new JTextField(10);

       calculateJB = new JButton ("Calculate");
       cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
       calculateJB.addActionListener (cbHandler);

       exitJB = new JButton ("Exit");
       ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
       exitJB.addActionListener (ebHandler);

       Container pane = getContentPane();
       pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (3, 2));

       pane.add(wordJL);
       pane.add(wordTF);
       pane.add(calculateJB);
       pane.add(exitJB);
       pane.add(sumJL);
       pane.add(sumTF);


       setSize(Width, Height);
       setVisible (true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class CalculateButtonHandler  implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource().equals(calculateJB))
            {


            double letterSum;

            letterSum = sumCharValues(wordTF.getText());
            sumTF.setText(letterSum+"");
            }

        }
    }

    private int sumCharValues (String input){
        String total = input.toLowerCase();
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0, n = total.length(); i < n; i++) {
            char c = total.charAt(i);
            result += (c - 'a' + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
          System.exit (0);  
        }
    }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    NumerologyEC rectObject = new NumerologyEC();
    }


}
```